# issue while inserting data in hbase using ImportTsv

Tags: hadoop, hbase, hive

I was trying to insert the data in hbase using the following commands:

```
hbase org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.ImportTsv -Dimporttsv.columns=HBASE_ROW_KEY,f:pageviews,f:visit -Dimporttsv.separator=\001 -Dimporttsv.bulk.output=output modelvar /000000.gz


hbase org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.LoadIncrementalHFiles modelvar output
```

where `modelvar` is the final hbase table in which data is suppose to be stored. `output` is the HDFS path where Hfiles are stored. Now the problem is the data which i was trying to insert is the output of hive. So, default separator would be `\001` which i can't change. So, I kept the `-Dimporttsv.separator=` value to be `\001`. But, we can't keep the multiple character as a separator. So, how do i insert the data in `hbase` written by `hive`

Comment: 1. have you tried to use "^A" (ASCII equivalent of \001)as seperator or other option is put the custom separator while outputting data from hive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMO, you can't use byte in the hadoop configuration.

But we can notice the property 'importtsv.separator', defined by org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.ImportTsv.SEPARATOR_CONF_KEY  is Base64 encode in org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.ImportTsv:245

```
public static Job createSubmittableJob(Configuration conf, String[] args)
  throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {

    // Support non-XML supported characters
    // by re-encoding the passed separator as a Base64 string.
    String actualSeparator = conf.get(SEPARATOR_CONF_KEY);
    if (actualSeparator != null) {
      conf.set(SEPARATOR_CONF_KEY,
               Base64.encodeBytes(actualSeparator.getBytes()));
    }
    ...
}
```

Is decoded in org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.ImportTsv:92

```
protected void doSetup(Context context) {
    Configuration conf = context.getConfiguration();

    // If a custom separator has been used,
    // decode it back from Base64 encoding.
    separator = conf.get(ImportTsv.SEPARATOR_CONF_KEY);
    if (separator == null) {
      separator = ImportTsv.DEFAULT_SEPARATOR;
    } else {
      separator = new String(Base64.decode(separator));
    }
    ...
}
```

And finally is checked to be a single byte in org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.ImportTsv:97

```
public TsvParser(String columnsSpecification, String separatorStr) {
      // Configure separator
      byte[] separator = Bytes.toBytes(separatorStr);
      Preconditions.checkArgument(separator.length == 1,
        "TsvParser only supports single-byte separators");
      separatorByte = separator[0];
      ...
}
```

As a solution, I suggest you redeclare a main method which modify the configuration's properties before the execution.

```
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HBaseConfiguration;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.ImportTsv;

public class ImportTsvByteSeparator extends ImportTsv
{
    /**
     * Main entry point.
     *
     * @param args  The command line parameters.
     * @throws Exception When running the job fails.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

      // We just have to modify the configuration
      Configuration conf = HBaseConfiguration.create();
      int byteSeparator = conf.getInt("importtsv.byte_separator", 001);
      String separator = Character.toString((char) byteSeparator);
      conf.set("importtsv.separator", separator);

      // Now we call ImportTsv main's method
      ImportTsv.main(args);
    }
}
```

I don't think we can overwrite some method inside the process (as createSubmittableJob()) because of the visibility of the attributes.

Answer (score 1):

Finally found an answer, replace the separator as `$(echo -e "\002")`. This works for all shell commands.